# Getting value from WHEN part while a condition meets using EXISTS keyword in drools

Tags: drools

```
rule "attaching AV and impact rating"
agenda-group "evaluate likelihood"
dialect "java"
when
     Application($threatList:getThreatList())
     $av:AttackVector()
     exists  $threat:Application.Threats(impact == "Disclose Information")from $threatList
     exists  AttackVector($av == AttackVector.REQUEST_MANIPULATION)
then
     RiskRating riskRating=new RiskRating($threat.getImpactRating(),$av.getLikelihood(),$av.getName());
     insertLogical(riskRating);
end
```

I am working on getting the object `$threat` in THEN part of the above-mentioned rule. If I run the above rule, it says:

```
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='attaching AV and impact rating']
referee/security/attack/Rule_attaching_AV_and_impact_rating1426933818.java (7:1053) : $threat cannot be resolved
```

If I loop through it and get the value in the THEN part, it causes a CARTESIAN product and inserts the values a number of times in the session. My rule looks like this when I get the cartesian product.

```
rule "attaching AV and impact rating"
agenda-group "evaluate likelihood"
dialect "java"
when
     Application($threatList:getThreatList())
     $av:AttackVector()
     exists  $threat:Application.Threats(impact == "Disclose Information")from $threatList
     $threat:Application.Threats(impact == "Disclose Information")from $threatList
     exists  AttackVector($av == AttackVector.REQUEST_MANIPULATION)
then
     RiskRating riskRating=new RiskRating($threat.getImpactRating(),$av.getLikelihood(),$av.getName());
     insertLogical(riskRating);
end
```

How do I get the value of `$threat` in THEN part without having the cartesian product?

Comment: Logical insertions rely on `Object.equals()`. Do you have it overriden?

Comment: @mike no. I didn't override it. Would that solve the issue?

Comment: @Mike I am having problems while working with $threat variable. rest is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `exists` operation entirely.

```
rule "attaching AV and impact rating"
agenda-group "evaluate likelihood"
dialect "java"
when
     Application($threatList:getThreatList())
     $av: AttackVector()
     $threat: Application.Threats(impact == "Disclose Information")from $threatList
     exists(AttackVector($av == AttackVector.REQUEST_MANIPULATION))
then
     RiskRating riskRating=new RiskRating($threat.getImpactRating(),$av.getLikelihood(),$av.getName());
     insertLogical(riskRating);
end
```

`exists` means "there is a thing in working memory that matches these conditions/looks like this". It's not used to actually extract or provide a reference to that matching instance. Simply remove the operator and it works as you need -- if there is an `Application.Threats` that matches your conditions, the rule triggers and the matching value is assigned to the `$threat` variable.

What you're running into is the fact that you have *multiple* threats that mean your condition, which is why you're having multiple triggers of the rule -- it will trigger once per matching `Application.Threats`. The `exists` keyword mitigates this because it only cares that at least one match exists, but you don't get a reference (because if there's four matches which one will be assigned to the variable? it doesn't make sense, logically.)

So you need to change your rule so that it *won't* fire multiple times and will instead only fire once when it finds a match. Usually you'd do this by making the consequences do something to working memory that makes the rule no longer eligible to be fired. In your example, you insert a RiskRating object; you could, then, check that no risk rating exists in your conditions:

```
not( RiskRating( /* insert criteria here or leave empty */ ) )
```

Alternatively you could retract something from working memory that your rule relies on to be present or a match. For example, if you don't need it for anything later on, you could retract the attack vector:

```
retract( $av )
```

Yet another option might be to try and update your `getThreatList()` implementation to return a Set instead so you don't have duplicates (assuming threats are considered duplicates based on the 'impact' field.) Or you could try to remove all Application.Threats instances that match the criteria from the threatlist being returned.

We simply don't know enough about your use case or rule set to know what data you need or what it looks like, but at the end of the day you simply need the rule to fire once and only once, so to do this you need to somehow update the rule to know that it's no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also overrode the equals() and hasCode() and the cartesian product is gone.